# Filtering for Max Date in SQL when Multiple Records have the Same Date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I have a dataset that includes the following fields: `building_id`, `lease_id`, `date_signed`

I am trying to get the most recent lease signed for each building_id. The issue I'm running into is that several of the leases have the same date signed in the building and I only want to include one of them. I have been using SnowSQL and was looking into using the Rank window function, but that gives the same rank value to records that have the same date in the building.

Is there a way to pull only one value for the most recent lease date for each building even if there are multiple leases with that same date? I will also need to know which lease it is associated with. Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Appreciate the advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.  Something like:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify row_number() over (partition by building_id order by date_signed desc) = 1;
```

Comment: think you misssed a 1 at the end of that.